# How to add CheckBox object in table in JAVA Swing

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, awt

I am having a table which is getting data from database. But I want to add a row with checkbox having attributes as name But everytime I run the program it show the value as

> `javax.swing.JCheckBox[ , 0, 0, 0x0, invalid, alignmentX = 0.0, alignmentY = 0.5, border = java................`

Here is the code.

```
while(rs.next()) {

    Vector row = new Vector();

    String name = rs.getString("name");
    String catid = rs.getString("catalogid");
    String brand = rs.getString("brand");
    String counter = rs.getString("counter");
    String qty = rs.getString("qty");
    String price = rs.getString("column_price");

    row.add(name);
    row.add(catid);
    row.add(brand);
    row.add(counter);
    row.add(qty);
    row.add(price);

    cb = new JCheckBox(name, true);
    row.add(cb);
    model.addRow(row);
}
```

Comment: it is better to paste the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add components to the TableModel of a JTable. You add data and use renderers to render the data.

So in your case you need to:

1. add `Boolean.TRUE` as the data to the `TableModel`.
2. override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the `TableModel` to return `Boolean.class` so the table can render the Boolean object as a check box.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information and examples to get you started.